# cfhtmltopdf with remote PDF service returning "FILE NOT FOUND"

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, coldfusion-11

I'm developing with CF11 on a Mac, which doesn't support having a local PDF Service to use with the new  tag.  But, I'm able to set up a PDF service that points to our dev (Windows) server.  That service verifies via the admin.

However, when I try to do a simple test:

```
<cfhtmltopdf>
    Hello
</cfhtmltopdf>
```

I get an error of "Error occurred while generating PDF" with the error detail of "Reason: FILE NOT FOUND".  If we try this code directly on the dev server (so it's using the local PDF service), it works just fine.

Anyone have an idea of what file it's referring to or what else may be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it came down to the need to start the PDF service manager.

*You need to go into ColdFusion Administrator, navigate to the "PDF Service" (under the "DATA & SERVICES" section). You will want to start the service that you want running by pressing the **play button to the left of the service**.*

I believe this will resolve your issue.

Comment: It's been a while (and we've since abandoned that whole idea, because it didn't accomplish our overall goal), but I'm fairly certain we had verified that the service was running. Thanks, though.